# How to use FIND_IN_SET on a multiselect attribute filter with an AND condition?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, product-collection, collection-filtering

I have a product collection which is being filtered on a custom multiselect attribute called 'apartment_includes'. This is used on a site for people looking to rent a room for a short period of time. The idea is to allow the user to specify the things that they want in a room, and select from the returned items. However, the query being generated at the moment uses

```
 AND (((FIND_IN_SET('34', e.apartment_includes)) OR (FIND_IN_SET('33', e.apartment_includes))))
```

meaning that it will return rooms that have air conditioning OR a balcony, instead of only returning rooms that have both, which is somewhat counter-intuitive for a user.

The filter is being set as follows:

```
foreach ($filters as $key => $filter) {
    $_productCollection->addFieldToFilter($key, $filter);
}
```

I have done a lot of searching and can find plenty of information on how to force the use of OR, but nobody mentions how to do the opposite. 
Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this please?

Comment: Is that a getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection() ? I can only see finest being used in CatalogSearch

Comment: You could try to manipulate the Zend_Db_Select object directly: `$_productCollection->getSelect()->where($key, $filter, null, true)`